# Deploying a Play 2.1 App with Tomcat

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, tomcat7

I have a play app I've converted to a .war file with [play2war](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) and now need to deploy that to tomcat.

Which files do I have to move over to my webapps directory within tomcat and do I need to unpack the war file?

Using Tomcat 7, FYI.

Comment: Tomcat should unpack it itself, but you can unpack it, if you want. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Check also this wiki page https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Deployment. The name of the war should be the same as the value of `application.context` property in the `application.conf`

Comment: You only need the war.

Answer (score 2):

The questions was already answered in the comments.

With 'play war' you can generate the war file. Copy this file to the webapps folder and tomcat will unpack it.

https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Usage

https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Deployment